# failed to initialize database, got error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused panic: An error occured

Tags: mysql, docker, go, go-gorm, go-gin

When I run my code using `go run` . it runs and the database tables get created successfully, but when I use `docker run mybackend:multistage` , I get this error:

```
failed to initialize database, got error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
panic: An error occured
```

**This is the code. Every database detail is correct**

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func NewDB() (*DB, error) {
    dsn := "joelwasike:joelwasike@tcp(localhost:3306)/talk?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

    // Open the database connection.
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("An error occured")

    }

    return &DB{db}, nil
}
```

Comment: This is mostly the mysql is on your host. the first go run on the same host so the loopback ip 127.0.0.1 works, but when build the application in a docker container, they have different ip. you should use the ip in the docker network.

Comment: change `localhost`  to `host.docker.internal` ,I would also suggest to pick this connection string from the environment variables, Rather than hardcoded in application.

Comment: One trick is to not swallow the actual error as it might contain valuable information.

Comment: Thanks y'all. host.docker.internal works